# Getting the first data.html instead of the second one. Why?

Tags: javascript, html

In the following code I am requesting to insert two data files into two different pages.

I am doing the same function for both with different var(s) (the second big block of code here) but I don't know why I'm getting the same data-**one**.html instead of data-**two**.html.

**data-one.html**

```
var x = document.getElementById("datahandeler"); /*save html element in var*/
x.addEventListener("click", reqListener); /*attach event listener to the element*/

/*event listener function*/
function reqListener () {
  var y = document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = (this.responseText); 
}  /*grab the insertable content area replace response */

var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.addEventListener("load", reqListener); /*attach event listener to the http request*/
oReq.open("GET", "data/data-one.html"); /*get data */
oReq.send(); /*send data*/
```

**data-two.html**

```
var x1 = document.getElementById("datahandeler1"); /*save html element in var*/
x1.addEventListener("click", reqListener); /*attach event listener to the element*/

/*event listener function*/
function reqListener () {
  var y1 = document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = (this.responseText); 
}  /*grab the insertable content area replace response */

var oReq1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq1.addEventListener("load", reqListener); /*attach event listener to the http request*/
oReq1.open("GET", "data/data-two.html"); /*get data */
oReq1.send(); /*send data*/
```

Answer (score 0):

When you define the second function with the same name as the first `regListener`, it overwrites the first definition.  There can be only one function with a given name in a particular scope.

So, when you define the second copy of `reqListener()`, it overwrites and replaces the first definition and you end up with only one copy of `reqListener()` which behaves like the second one.

Change the names of your functions to be unique:

```
/*event listener function*/
function reqListener1 () {
  var y = document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = (this.responseText); 
}  /*grab the insertable content area replace response */

var x = document.getElementById("datahandeler"); /*save html element in var*/
x.addEventListener("click", reqListener1); /*attach event listener to the element*/


var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.addEventListener("load", reqListener1); /*attach event listener to the http request*/
oReq.open("GET", "data/data-one.html"); /*get data */
oReq.send(); /*send data*/



/*event listener function*/
function reqListener2 () {
  var y1 = document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = (this.responseText); 
}  /*grab the insertable content area replace response */

var x1 = document.getElementById("datahandeler1"); /*save html element in var*/
x1.addEventListener("click", reqListener2); /*attach event listener to the element*/

var oReq1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq1.addEventListener("load", reqListener2); /*attach event listener to the http request*/
oReq1.open("GET", "data/data-two.html"); /*get data */
oReq1.send(); /*send data*/
```

FYI, your code commenting style is difficult to read and follow.  I'm glad to see the comments, but some styles of inserting comments are much easier to follow than others.

---

Also, it is not clear why you're trying to use the same event handler for an Ajax event and for a click event.  These are different events.  The event handler will have a different value for `this` and there will be no `this.responseText` on the client event.  So, something appears wrong with the client events, but it isn't clear what you're trying to do some I'm not sure what to suggest exactly.

---

Perhaps, all these should just be inline, anonymous and separate event handlers so there is no naming conflict:

```
document.getElementById("datahandeler").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    // handle the click event for datahandeler here
    // not sure what you expected to do here
});

var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

// attach event listener to the http request
oReq.addEventListener("load", function() {'
    // put ajax result into content area
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = this.responseText;
}); 
// get data
oReq.open("GET", "data/data-one.html");
// send data
oReq.send();
```

---

Or (this is just a guess), if you're trying to run the ajax call when the element is clicked, you can do that like this:

```
document.getElementById("datahandeler").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // attach event listener to the http request
    oReq.addEventListener("load", function() {'
        // put ajax result into content area
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }); 
    // get data
    oReq.open("GET", "data/data-one.html");
    // send data
    oReq.send();
});
```

Comment: `this.responseType` with `this == <#content>`. Might be the problem too.

Comment: @LeonAdler - Yeah, you're right.  I'll add info about that.